# For which $N$ is it possible to alter one side of an equilateral triangle of side length $N$ to get another triangle of integer side lengths, ...?

Tags: geometry, triangles

This question is "inspired" by the [*Rupsa and Equilateral Triangle*](https://www.codechef.com/OCT15/problems/ADTRI) problem from Code Chef's "October Challenge 2015". The deadline of 12 October 2015 has passed.

Given an equilateral triangle having length of each side as an integer $N$. We need to tell if it is possible to transform the triangle keeping two sides fixed and alter the third side such that it still remains a triangle, but the altered side will have its length as an even integer, and the line drawn from the opposite vertex to the mid-point of the altered side is of integral length.

Example: If $N=5$ the answer is *yes*, while if $N=3$ the answer is *no*.

Comment: can you please attach a diagram?

Comment: What do you mean by "transform the triangle keeping two sides fixed"?

Comment: That's very obfuscated. but all they are really asking is to create right triangles  where the hypotenuse is the original N integer, but the legs can be any no integers.  So it's asking which integers can be the largest of a pythagorean triplet.

Answer (score 1):

Sure. The side length must be the biggest of one of [Pythagorean triples](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pythagorean_triple).